# G++ -S Doesn't output Assembly file in Linux

Tags: assembly, g++

For the past hour, I have been trying to output the assembly file of a cpp file i wrote using g++ -s fileName.cpp. The command in terminal executes, but the assembly file is not present in file directory. Help!

Thank you.

Comment: What does `g++ -S -o asm.s fileName.cpp` give you? Do you have the proper permissions to create files in the directory you are running this in?

Comment: whoa that fixed it. Why doesn't g++ -S filename.cpp work bu g++ -S -o asm.s filename.cpp works?

Comment: Not sure, but it is generally best practice to specify an output file (-o).

Comment: The default output file would be `fileName.o` (when using `-S`, that output file is not an object file but is in fact an assembly source file). It's a confusing default, so if you want to be explicit, use `-o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
g++ -S -o asm.s fileName.cpp
```

(Created answer from comment so question can be marked answered)